# Como faço pra quando tocar a musica começar rodar uma imagem?

Tags: javascript, jquery, imagem

Como faço pra quando tocar a musica começar rodar uma imagem? `javascript` ou `php`

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">
rodarImagem(
function adicionaClassERoda() {
    document.getElementById('pic').className = 'rodar';
});
</script>
<style>
.rodar {
    animation: rotation 2s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes rotation {
    from {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}
    to   {-webkit-transform: rotate(359deg);}
}
</style>

<div class="jp-controls">
    <img id="pic" src="img/cd1.jpg" style="width:100px; height:100px; position:absolute;"> <a href="#"><div class="jp-play" onclick="rodarImagem();" role="button" tabindex="0"><i class="fa fa-play-circle"></i></div></a>

    <div class="jp-previous" role="button" tabindex="0"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="jp-stop" onclick="pararImagem();" role="button" tabindex="0"><i class="fa fa-stop"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="jp-next" role="button" tabindex="0"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Que música? Rodar você quer dizer rotacionar? Você quer a solução em PHP ou Javascript?  E por que colocou a tag Java? Está muito difícil de entender o que você quer, por favor edite a questão, adicione algum código relacionado a sua dúvida. Nos ajude a te ajudar.

Comment: pow cara eu to fazendo um site de musica e gostaria de saber como faço pra quando a musica começar a tocar, uma imagem começar a girar(rotacionar) continuamente ate a musica parar? em javascript

Comment: Como está tocando a música na página? Com HTML5, Flash, Silverlight? Sabe como capturar os eventos de play/pause da música?

Comment: eu estou utilizando plugin jplayer que necessita do jquery e ja esta tudo funcionando corretamente eu so quero implementar essa função de girar imagem continuamente ate a musica parar, me perdoe se nao estiver deixando as coisas claras, e pq estou sou novo no ramo de pragamação javascript

Comment: Adicionei a outra solução :)

Comment: Resolveu seu problema?

Answer (score 1):

## Utilizando biblioteca extensão [`rotate`](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-rotate/) do JQuery

```js
var angulo = 1;
var rodar = function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        $("#pic").rotate(angulo);
    }, 100);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://jquery-rotate.googlecode.com/files/jquery.rotate.1-1.js"></script>

<input type="button" id="btn" value="Rodar!" onclick="rodar();" />
<br/>
<img id="pic" src="http://precollegiate.stanford.edu/circle/math/12circles.png" />
```

-

-

## Solução com **CSS 3** e **javascript puro**:

```js
function adicionaClassERoda() {
    document.getElementById('pic').className = 'rodar';
}
```

```css
.rodar {
    animation: rotation 2s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes rotation {
    from {transform: rotate(0deg);}
    to   {transform: rotate(359deg);}
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Rodar!" onclick="adicionaClassERoda()"/>
<br/>
<img id="pic" src="http://precollegiate.stanford.edu/circle/math/12circles.png">
```

Comment: muito bom cara, mais eu tenho mais uma duvida, tem como deixar a imagem girando mais sem se movimentar sobre a pagina?

Comment: @matheus coloquei outra solução com CSS 3 que funciona do jeito que você quer

Comment: pow cara muito abrigado pela a ajuda, so mais uma duvida tem como eu implementar isso no meu player de musica? tipo quando começar tocar a musica a imagem começar a girar e quando a musica parar a imagem parar de girar tambem

Comment: @matheus A música toca somente quando é apertado o play? `<a href="#" class="jp-play">Play</a>` por exemplo?

Comment: `<a href="#" class="jp-play" onclick="rodarImagem();">Play</a>`
`<a href="#" class="jp-play" onclick="pararImagem();">Stop</a>` e na função você adicione e remove a className respectivamente

Comment: sim sim mais pra a imagem parar de girar quando automaticamente a musica parar de tocar ou quando der um pause na musica?

Comment: pow cara muito obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: vou testar agora no meu site

Comment: Se a solução resolveu o seu problema, marca como a resposta certa fazendo favor para facilitar as visitas posteriores.

Comment: cara o meu botao pra disparar a função esta assim(<a href="#"><div class="jp-play" onclick="rodarImagem();" role="button" tabindex="0"><i class="fa fa-play-circle"></i></div></a>)  e o javascript e css assim (<script type="text/javascript">
rodarImagem(
function adicionaClassERoda() {
    document.getElementById('pic').className = 'rodar';
});
</script>
<style>
.rodar {
    animation: rotation 2s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes rotation {
    from {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}
    to   {-webkit-transform: rotate(359deg);}
}</style>)

Comment: nao deu certo nao

Comment: @matheus posta os códigos na sua pergunta pra facilitar

Comment: @matheus pelo oq vejo está errado seu javascript

Comment: pow cara eu to aprendendo sobre javascript agora